# How to decrease Crystal Report loading time?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am facing  problem related to loading of crystal reports. Language used is VB.Net and database is MS Sql Server 2008 R2.

My crystal reports takes unusually more time to load, so we have to wait long. How can i reduce the loading time of crystal reports?

Comment: Can you please post the SP used behind binding?

Comment: what is sp ???
can you explain some information about the sp

Comment: we are using crystal report in framework 2.0 ,and crystal report 9 version

Comment: You really need to supply information that will allow us to help you. How long is long? Are you using tables or stored procedure (SP)? If tables, how many? Are they from the same database? Are you using a dataset as your report source or are you tied directly to SQL Server? If SP, then how long does it take to run? Try grabbing your SQL and put it into SQL Server and run it, how long does it take? So on, and so forth. The more you give us, the more likely it is that you will get the answer that helps.

Comment: put some code those are using for loading data.

Answer (score 0):

May be the reason behind that delay is : you do not mange relationships between tables that crystal report take data from.

Comment: after your crystal report take time , does it came with wrong data?

Comment: No data is correct but It takes so much time in displaying report??

Comment: So how can I manage relationship between tables so I can get crystal reports rapidly???

Comment: read this article i hope it solve your problem [link](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-multiple-tables.htm)

Comment: http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-multiple-tables.htm

Comment: i have see link but these kind of work is alrewady done in my crystal reports.

Comment: try to create Crystal Report that take data from one table and see if return right data